# Creating and making an shortcut appear on Start Menu

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pocketpc

I'm maintain an Pocket PC 2003/CF.NET application and would like to
automagically create an shortcut on Start Menu on first run.

So far, so good. I created the LNK file and put it on Start Menu folder,
but Windows only shows 7 app slots on it - I had to manually uncheck an 
app to make it appear on Start.

How to automate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this takes me back

When you install using an inf file via cab install adding more than 7 shortcuts to the start menu they will end up in the \Start Menu\Programs.

I don't think you can automate removing items from someone's startmenu bar as this could be malicious.

Comment: It's an company device, so there's no 'personal settings' problem.